# How to render two react list groups in the same container, chronologically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, frontend

Basically, im looking to merge the two containers to be in one single container, with the most recent of either at the top.

**So instead of**

Most recent post

second recent post

third recent post

Most recent event

second recent event

third recent event

**It is merged to be:**

Most recent post

Second recent post

Most recent event

third recent post
econd recent event

third recent event

Heres what the code currently looks like:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MenuBar />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <PostContainer />
            <EventContainer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

These "containers" are identical:

```
render(){
    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
          <PostView
            key={post.id}
            id={post.id}
            title={post.title}
            description={post.description}
            region={REGION_CHOICES[post.region]}
            datetimeCreated={post.datetime_created}
            creator={post.creator}
            likedUsers= {post.liked_users}
            taggedUsers={post.tagged_users}
            handleLike={this.handleLike}
          />
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
    )
  }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks, everyone

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change `PostContainer` and `EventContainer` into plain javascript classes?

Both could have functions which return a specified post/event Component. For posts, it could look something like this:

```
class Posts {
    var postStore = [PostComponent1, PostComponent2, ...]

    function getPost(index) {
        return postStore[index];
    }
}
```

Then, you can make the React Component a more generic class, `Container`, which does something like this:

```
import posts from './posts'
import events from './events'

class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        var postsAndEvents = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            postsAndEvents.push(posts.getPost(i))
            postsAndEvents.push(events.getEvent(i))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {postsAndEvents.map((Component) => {
                    return <Component />
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You can build the `postsAndEvents` array however you wish. The main idea is that you have to elevate the state (in this case, the state being the order of components). React Components do not return data to their owners.

Comment: I like the idea, how would I populate the posts and events array with my Axios get requests?

Comment: It depends on how those Axios requests are formatted, but I'd probably write an async method which `await`s the axios response (which I assume contains the posts) to update the `postStore` array, still using the push method. In that case, you may want to have the `posts` class take some sort of callback, so that it can alert the `Container` when it's ready. That way the container could re-fetch the post components

Comment: actually, upon review, I need to keep them as components, I use them individually elsewhere. I appreciate the thought out response though!